# Getting "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError was thrown" while opening pdf file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf-generation

I am developing an application in vb.net it was working perfectly fine until this error occurred.  I have tried everything but its of no use. Please Help me

> **ERROR:**
>   Server Error in '/CNS/pdf' Application.
>
> Exception of type java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError was thrown. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
>   current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about 
>   the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Exception of type 
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError was thrown.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1165:                    CheckedByName = dr.GetString(1)
>   Line 1166:                    CheckedByDesig = dr.GetString(2)
>   Line 1167:                Case 3
>   Line 1168:                    ApprovedByName = dr.GetString(1)
>   Line 1169:                    ApprovedByDesig = dr.GetString(2)
>
> Source File: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\CNS\pdf\PdfForms.aspx.vb Line: 1167
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [UnsatisfiedLinkError: Exception of type java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError was 
>   thrown.]
>     java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError.checkAndThrowException(Throwable 
>   thrown) +59
>      java.io.File..cctor() +246
>
> [TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for "java.io.File" threw an 
>   exception.]
>      java.io.FileOutputStream..ctor(String path) +28
>      pdf.PdfForms.ShowPO(String PONo) in 
>   C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\CNS\pdf\PdfForms.aspx.vb:1167
>      pdf.PdfForms.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in 
>   C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\CNS\pdf\PdfForms.aspx.vb:52
>      System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +67
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +35
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain() +750

Comment: Can you share the code in which you call the function? Going to be difficult to fix otherwise.

Comment: it is although a very huge function as i am setting the formats for pdf. can i post only that particular part of code?